# Selenium (Instagram Web Assistant Extension) called INSSIST

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I am trying to click the [+] Button in the INSSIST extension using selenium, but I just get an error everytime. I just want to know if it is possible to click it. Can't figure it out

For the code to work you have to make sure you got the chrome inssist extension and you have close all instances of chrome otherwise it will not load selenium correctly, because it is a background extension aswell

Here is the online instagram alternative called inssist

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/inssist-web-client-for-in/bcocdbombenodlegijagbhdjbifpiijp

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
chrome_options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Alexander Smith\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
chrome_options.add_argument('profile-directory=Profile 2')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\\Users\\Alexander Smith\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)

driver.get("chrome-extension://bcocdbombenodlegijagbhdjbifpiijp/inssist.html#instagram.com/")

print("Good")
create = WebDriverWait(driver,9).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//\*\[@id="mount_0_0_3c"\]/div/div/div/div\[1\]/div/div/div/div\[1\]/div\[1\]/div\[1\]/div/div/div/div/div\[1\]/div')))
print("Good")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(create)
print("Good")
create.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: _just get an error everytime_: What error do you see?

Comment: I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "j:/INSISST.py", line 20, in <module>
    create = WebDriverWait(driver,9).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mount_0_0_3c"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div')))
  File "C:\Users\Alexander Smith\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:

Comment: I'm facing _`bcocdbombenodlegijagbhdjbifpiijp is blocked`_, _`This page has been blocked by Chrome`_ and _`ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`_ trying to access `chrome-extension://bcocdbombenodlegijagbhdjbifpiijp/inssist.html#instagram.com/` even manually.

Comment: Oh I know why you are facing that problem. That is because you don't have the chrome extension for it. I tried copy the chrome extension link to a profile which doesn't have the extension, and I get the same message

Comment: @sound wave is this something you would be able to answer or figure out? :)